# Can I select two date range in a same month like(01/05/2017 to 01/17/2017) and other (01/19/2017 to 01/31/2017) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, reactjs

I saw many jQuery plugin for date range like https://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/ but saw only one pair of range can select in month. I want to make a multidaterange picker in which one can select more then one date range in a single month like first range is (01/05/2017 to 01/17/2017) and other (01/19/2017 to 01/31/2017).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIfcy.png)

Comment: Why AngularJS has tagged here?

Comment: It will be helpful for me in any framework of js,I need idea

Comment: Why don't you take two different elements to achieve this ?

Comment: Sorry @rahul_m I am not getting you. Coz I need to put both range in single month.

Comment: Ok, 01/05/2017 to 01/17/2017 Mark this in one input and 01/19/2017 to 01/31/2017 mark this in another input, I means I am trying to say, to use input elements.